# What is the actual gasPrice used in a Truffle + Ganache environment?

Tags: web3js, truffle, gas, gas-price

It doesn't seem to match the Ganache UI, nor web3 gas price.

Answer (score 3):

The price of gas seems to be quite elusive in the ethereum world for a variety of reasons. In this context, it's because the supposed `gasPrice` isn't correct. The UI in Ganache and the value reported via web3 (and the value you set as the default on a contract in truffle tests for example) are all wrong. You have two options in the currently released versions: use the empirical value I've reported in [this issue](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache/issues/314) = 100000000000 OR manually set the `gasPrice` on each transaction.

I'm using Ganache 1.0.1 and Truffle 4.0.5